# Missing Dots for Chapters in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

I have a strange formatting problem in my table of contents. For some reason, the dots following chapters do not extend as far as those for sections and subsections.

I have included a MWE below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em} 

\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} 
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 2}
\subsection{Example 3}

\end{document}
```

I have highlighted the place of the missing dot in the image below

[image]

Comment: The page number for chapters is in bold, hence is a little bit wider than the non-bold, and leaves narrower space for the dotted filling. Also the dots are filling from left to right, hence it's a coincidence that those dots in different toc lines look aligned.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Is there a way to fix this such that the chapters align and are in bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I said in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615007/missing-dots-for-chapters-in-table-of-contents?noredirect=1#comment1536202_615007) is  close, and only close to the point. TeX will automatically make the box leaders aligned, as far as the boxes has equal width. See [`texdoc texbytopic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), sec. 9.2.2 "Box Leaders". Here `tocloft` uses a box leader

```tex
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern #1 mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern #1 mu$}\hfill
```

in which for chapters the `\cftdot` is in bold, hence makes the box wider and not aligned with that box for sections.

The following example tries to make the box used by leader has equal width.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em} 

\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} 
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }

% make dots in toc aligned
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\cftdotfill
  {\hbox{\cftdot}}
  {\hbox to 3pt{\hss\cftdot}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\cftsetpnumwidth{1em} % initially 1.55em

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 2}
\subsection{Example 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the bold dots are slightly wider than the regular dots. You need to change (reduce) the spacing between bold dots to get them to match with the regular dots. The following does this but might need a little adjustment for your particular case.

```
% tocdotsprob.tex  SE 615007

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em} 

\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} 
%\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{4.4} % the default is 4.5
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{4.3} %%%% adjust this to suit
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
\section{Example 2}
\subsection{Example 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]